# ConstraintLayout to match on siblings view height whichever is higher

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, androidx

Suppose i have 2 Views. Those 2 have a text value that can be either the view with id tvLabel can be bigger in height compared to clValueContainer that can be bigger also. Now I want to make the 2 views follow their height whichever has bigger height will copy the another. Any idea on this one?

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLabel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/_35sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_1sdp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/_12sdp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_12sdp"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_3sdp"
        android:text="@{label}"
        android:textColor="@color/color_light"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
        android:gravity="start|center"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/clValueContainer"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/clValueContainer"
        tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry"
        tools:text="@string/rental_reversions"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/clValueContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_1sdp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/_6sdp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_6sdp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvLabel"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tvLabel">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvValue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:minWidth="@dimen/_40sdp"
            android:text="@{score ? @string/provided : @string/missing}"
            android:textColor="@color/color_dark"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|end"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:padding="@dimen/_6sdp"
            app:data="@{score}"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry"
            tools:text="10.0"
            tools:background="@drawable/rounded_green"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it, I will explain below how I get it. See the new code below:

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/clRowContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/_35sdp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_1sdp"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/_12sdp"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_12sdp"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_3sdp"
            android:text="@{label}"
            android:textColor="@color/color_light"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
            android:gravity="start|center"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/clValueContainer"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/clValueContainer"
            tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry"
            tools:text="@string/rental_reversions"/>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/clValueContainer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_1sdp"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/_6sdp"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_6sdp"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvLabel"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tvLabel">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/tvValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minWidth="@dimen/_40sdp"
                android:text="@{score ? @string/provided : @string/missing}"
                android:textColor="@color/color_dark"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|end"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:padding="@dimen/_6sdp"
                app:data="@{score}"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry"
                tools:text="10.0"
                tools:background="@drawable/rounded_green"/>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now, to fix the issue, since we want to copy its height, create 2 constraints bottom on each view and connect them to each other. make the layout height `wrap_content` on both view and done, it is already fixed.

This is also the same if you want to copy the width of other element which ever is bigger just contraint it to start or end of the element to each of them and set the width to wrap_content.

Comment: How to handle this if it has more than 2 views. If it is more than 2 views we cannot map the bottom constraint to each other height